# Google deployment manager access nested properties with --properties argument

Tags: google-deployment-manager

If I'm using a Jinja template I can override properties via command line like this:

```
--properties zone:us-central1-a,machineType:n1-standard-1,image:debian-9
```

But I see no documentation or examples for doing this with nested properties like labels or environmentVariables for example:

```
resources:
  - name: resource-name
    type: 'gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions'
    properties:
      labels:
        testlabel1: testlabel1value
        testlabel2: testlabel2value
      environmentVariables:
        TEST: 'zzzzzzzzz'
```

How do set properties like these? This does not work: `--properties labels:testlabel1:newvalue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is that the `--properties` flag is not meant to pass property values to the template. A template cannot run without a configuration file, the --properties flag is meant to replace the config file. Each parameter you pass is the same as listing them in a config file.

Essentially using `--template my-template.py --properties zone:us-central1-f` is the equivalent of running `--config myConfig.yaml` where the YAML is defined as such:

```
imports:
- path: my-template.py

resources:
- name: some-resource
  type: my-temaplte.py
  properties:
    zone: us-central1-f
```

The `--properties` flag is not meant to pass raw data to replace non-variables.

Although this does not directly answer your question, you shouldn't normally need to define nested values in the flag. Your template will generally call on direct variables taken from the object `properties`.

despite this, I did try some tests, and as far as I can tell, you can't do this.

Comment: bummer. one obvious use case i have is that it would be nice to set environmentVariables via command line so i can have just one template and change env vars for dev and prod deploys- would be nice for CI\CD

Comment: That's actually what the command is for, it just depends how you define the variables in the template. For python, define the variables as `context.properties['variable']` and `{{ properties['variable'] }}` for jinja. It won't matter if the field is nested in the template, the source of the variable will still be located under `properties`

Comment: This does present certain hurdles, such as fields that rely on lists of items that may have variable lengths. I can't find a way to overcome that for this use case, though if you use the config yaml and a template, you can manage to iterate over lists. I have some examples [here](https://github.com/Aahzymandius/deployment-manager)

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I managed to pass an object via command line like this:

```
--properties ^~^labels:{'testlabel1: testlabel1value','testlabel2: testlabel2value'}~environmentVariables:{'TEST: zzzzzzzzz'}
```

- This sequence of symbols **^~^** is how you can change delimiter. You have to put it at the beginning of your properties. More info about escaping you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping).
- I put single apostrophe over single key value pair because we need that space between key and value. Otherwise it's  interpereted as key with null value.
- If you're using Bash shell you should also escape **{**,**}** symbols.